# AWS API Gateway throwing 'ClientError' when invoking Lambda function for retrieving images from S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

> {"errorMessage": "An error occurred () when calling the ListObjects
> operation: ", "errorType": "ClientError", "requestId":
> "b56de67e-a5f8-4caf-ae26-78441dacffe2", "stackTrace": ["  File
> "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 11, in lambda_handler\n    for
> obj in bucket.objects.all():\n", "  File
> "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 81, in **iter**\n
> for page in self.pages():\n", "  File
> "/var/runtime/boto3/resources/collection.py", line 171, in pages\n
> for page in pages:\n", "  File "/var/runtime/botocore/paginate.py",
> line 269, in **iter**\n    response =
> self._make_request(current_kwargs)\n", "  File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/paginate.py", line 357, in _make_request\n
> return self._method(**current_kwargs)\n", "  File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 530, in _api_call\n
> return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n", "  File
> "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 960, in _make_api_call\n
> raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"]}

this error comes whenever i use the invoke URL from API Gateway.

I have two buckets (`icarscatalogue` which has two main files `catalogue.hml` and `json` file) then I have `catalogueimage` which has three images of car models. I cannot retrieve these images when I run the URL.

My lambda code (python)

```py
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    json_data = []
    
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3', endpoint_url="http://icarscatalogue.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com", region_name='us-east-1')
    
    bucket = s3.Bucket('catalogueimage')
    for obj in bucket.objects.all():
        s3_link = "https://s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/icarscatalogueimage/model_r.jpeg" + obj.key
        json_data.append({ "image" : s3_link })
        
        return {
            'statusCode' : 200,
            'body': json.dumps(json_data)
}
```

my `catalogueimage` bucket policy

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::catalogueimage/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::catalogueimage"
        }
    ]
}
```